# Is "export" only useful for temporary effects?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I know that,
Shell variables are not available to the parent or child shells and Shell environments are available for child shells.

When I want to permanently add current directory to PATH I can do it in 2 ways:

1-Normal way:

```
 [sinoosh@localhost ~]$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

[image]

2-without export command

[image]

And then logout i see the same result as normal way

[image]

there is not different between "1"&"2" . can we say the `export` command is useful for that time we do not want permanently add to environment variables?

What's happening here?

Comment: Please note that setting or changing environment variables in `~/.bash_profile` does not affect the graphical environment on a desktop. Therefore I wouldn't call it the "normal way". Please take a look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables

Answer (score 6):

The `export` (or `declare -x`) declaration makes the difference between a plain *shell variable* and an *environment variable*.

Since `PATH` is almost certainly already part of your environment - having been set in `/etc/environment` for example - marking it for export a second time isn't strictly necessary<sup>[1]</sup> (although it does no harm - and make the intent clear).

---

<sup>1</sup> at least I think that's the case - I'd like to find a primary reference

Comment: thank you, i think the reason is first time PATH is exported in `/etc/profile` but i am not sure

Comment: `PATH` is made an environment variable early (more early than via `/etc/profile`, @Sinoosh) , and yes, it's not needed to export it again after that. This can possibly be derived from the community wiki page [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Inheritance), but it isn't expressed very clear.

Comment: according to the  book of Ross Brunson     in login shell sessions we have these steps:1-loging to shell. 2-/etc/profile is sourced 3-/etc/profile.d are sourced 4-~/.bash_profile is sourced 5-~/.bashrc is sourced from within the ~/.bash_profile 6-user conducts her business 7-exit 8-.bash_logout is sourced.       do these steps are not complete?